# NSControl flickers on NSView attached to a NSView in full screen mode

Tags: objective-c, checkbox, fullscreen, nsview, subview

**The setup:**

1. My application has **background views** that are set into full screen mode using `enterFullScreenMode:withOptions:`.
2. To these **background views** I move a **content view** as a subview using `removeFromSuperview` and `addSubview:`.
3. Further, there is a **preferences view** that I add to the **content view** as described before.
   The **preferences view** comes from a XIB and contains **NSControls** like checkboxes, circular slides, combo box, ...

The whole setup is much more complicated which makes it very difficult to post code here. Nevertheless, I will add some parts if you request them.

**The problem:**
When I select any of the controls on the **preferences view** the elements flicker. That means the checkbox for example disappears and reappears. 
I already tried to solve the problem running `setNeedsDisplay:`, `setNeedsLayout` or `makeKeyAndOrderFront:` in the `viewDidMoveToSuperview` method of the view. Though, nothing helped. What can I do?

---

**Edit 1:**
I took a [screen capture](http://screencast.com/t/Hd6pBWYW) of the application so you can see what happens.

---

**Edit 2:**
Here is the `PreferencesViewController.h`:

```
//  PreferencesViewController.h

#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "SlideShowModelProtocol.h"
#import "DisplayInfoController.h"

@interface PreferencesViewController : NSViewController {
    id<SlideShowModelProtocol> m_localModel;
    DisplayInfoController* m_displayInfoController;
}

@property (readonly) id<SlideShowModelProtocol> localModel;
@property (readwrite, assign) IBOutlet DisplayInfoController* displayInfoController;

- (void)moveViewToSuperview:(NSView*)superview;
- (void)showOnView:(NSView*)superview;
- (void)removeViewFromSuperview;
- (BOOL)viewHasSuperview;
- (void)updateModelSettings;
- (IBAction)cancelView:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)confirmView:(id)sender;

@end
```

... and the implementation `PreferencesViewController.m`:

```
//  PreferencesViewController.m

#import "PreferencesViewController.h"
#import "ApplicationController.h"
#import "DisplayInfo.h"


@interface PreferencesViewController()

- (void)centerViewOnSuperview;
- (void)loadModel;

@end

@implementation PreferencesViewController


- (id)init {
    self = [super initWithNibName:@"PreferencesView" bundle:nil];
    if (self != nil) {
        m_localModel = nil;
        m_displayInfoController = nil; // Assigned in Interface Builder.
    }
    return self;
}

@synthesize localModel = m_localModel;
@synthesize displayInfoController = m_displayInfoController;

- (void)loadModel {
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"localModel"];
    // Retrieve deep copy of the model.
    m_localModel = [[[ApplicationController sharedController] model] copyWithZone:nil];
    // Reset the table view selection as saved in the model.
    NSIndexSet* selectionIndices = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:[[m_localModel selectedScreenIndex] unsignedIntegerValue]];
    [[m_displayInfoController displayInfoTableView] selectRowIndexes:selectionIndices byExtendingSelection:NO];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"localModel"];
}

/**
    Moves and positions the view on the given superview (aka another screen).
    @param superview A superview.
 */
- (void)showOnView:(NSView*)superview {
    [self moveViewToSuperview:superview];
    [self centerViewOnSuperview];
}

/**
    Moves the view on the given superview.
    @param superview A superview (In full screen mode a background view).
 */
- (void)moveViewToSuperview:(NSView*)superview {
    if ([[self view] superview] == superview) {
        return;
    }
    [self loadModel];
    [[self view] removeFromSuperview];
    [superview addSubview:[self view]];
}

- (void)removeViewFromSuperview {
    [[self view] removeFromSuperview];
}


- (void)centerViewOnSuperview {
    NSRect superviewFrame = self.view.superview.frame;
    NSRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
    float viewFrameWidth = viewFrame.size.width;
    float viewFrameHeight = viewFrame.size.height;
    float xPos = 0.5f * superviewFrame.size.width - 0.5f * viewFrameWidth;
    float yPos = 0.5f * superviewFrame.size.height - 0.5f * viewFrameHeight;
    NSRect frame = NSMakeRect(xPos, yPos, viewFrameWidth, viewFrameHeight);
    [self.view setFrame:frame];
}

- (BOOL)viewHasSuperview {
    return [[self view] superview] != nil;
}

- (void)updateModelSettings {
    id<SlideShowModelProtocol> globalModel = [[ApplicationController sharedController] model];
    [globalModel setFadeDuration:[m_localModel fadeDuration]];
    [globalModel setStayDuration:[m_localModel stayDuration]];
    [globalModel setStartWithFirst:[m_localModel startWithFirst]];
    [globalModel setSortingMode:[m_localModel sortingMode]];
    [globalModel setAnimationIsActive:[m_localModel animationIsActive]];
    [globalModel setSelectedScreenIndex:[m_localModel selectedScreenIndex]];
    [globalModel setPanAmount:[m_localModel panAmount]];
    [globalModel setZoomAmount:[m_localModel zoomAmount]];
    [globalModel setZoomFactor:[m_localModel zoomFactor]];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UserInterface

- (IBAction)cancelView:(id)sender {
    [[ApplicationController sharedController] hidePreferencesViewModelSettingsUpdated:NO];
}

- (IBAction)confirmView:(id)sender {
    ApplicationController* applicationController = [ApplicationController sharedController];
    if ([[applicationController model] isEqualToModel:m_localModel]) {
        [self cancelView:sender];
        return;
    }
    [self updateModelSettings];
    [applicationController hidePreferencesViewModelSettingsUpdated:YES];
}

@end
```

Comment: from what i could see from the screencast (when going frame by frame) it seems as if when you click on some of your controls you are sending a signal that eventually end up in your preference view being refreshed (maybe a save into preference file and reload from it). can you try two things:
**1** create another XIB with a button in it an load it in your pref view and tell us what happens when you click on it (no code involved on that button only pure UI thing)
**2** give us some portion of the code when you click on your controls (what technically happens)

Comment: Indeed it does not flicker when I add a new view which has no actions or bindings attached to its GUI elements. I added the `PreferencesViewController` class to let you see what happens there. The GUI elements of the view theirself have bindings to the `localModel`.

Comment: Some more facts: (1) I deleted the bindings for the GUI elements at the original `PreferencesView`. Though, the flickering did not went away. (2) When the `PreferencesView` (both variants) show up, all GUI elements are "white" and turn "blue" not until I click onto them or onto the view itself.

Comment: there are a fews things that could be corrected (for ex calling `initWithNibName` inside the init method is usually not a good idea because you are then mixing two [designated initializers](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ajlESsRXqmM)) but anyways this is not the problem here. I think the main issue comes from what `moveViewToSuperview` does and it is called in `showOnView` but I couldn't find where its called can you tell us ?

Comment: also can you comment the content of `showOnView` and tell us if you still see the flickering ?

Comment: I edited the setup description and added comments for the mentioned methods. Though, those are only called when I move the view to another screen but not if I interact with the `PreferencesView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already told in the comments to my post I created a new `PreferencesViewTest.xib` and added the GUI controls step by step. I also added the bindings, controllers and so on. Everything worked fine - no flickering. Then I assigned *RETURN* as the **key equivalent** for the *OK* button in Interface Builder. I started the application once again to check the behavior .... it flickers! I double checked the phenomenon with the former `PreferencesView.xib` by removing the **key equivalent** from the *OK* button .... it does not flicker! - Crazy shit. But why..?

Comment: wow indeed ! have you checked that you haven't overridden the `setKeyEquivalent` method by mistake or that you are not using a framework that would do so ?

Comment: definitely strange but i don't believe in magic ;) I'd be curious to know what's going on, is it only happening when you assign the RETURN key to your button ? what if you assign this key on a different button ?

Comment: The same effect can be seen when I assign the RETURN key to another button. The effect is not there if I use another key equivalent. Interesting enough, hitting the RETURN key still closes the view when it is not assigned to the button.